# How to use calc css function in react render

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

Hi i have issue to use calc in my render function in react.

```
    render() {
        let top =0;
        let left =0;
        if(this.props.top !==undefined){
            top=this.props.top;
        }
        if(this.props.left !==undefined){
            left=this.props.left;
        }

        let topval = `calc(50% + ${top})`, leftval = `calc(50% + ${left })`;
        console.log(topval);
        console.log(leftval);
        return (
            <div className={"d-flex flex-column justify-content-center text-center position-absolute loading-animation"}
            style={{top:topval,left:leftval,transform:("translate(-50%,-50%)")}}>
                <div>
                    <Spinner animation="grow" variant="success" />
                    <Spinner animation="grow" variant="danger" />
                    <Spinner animation="grow" variant="warning" />
                </div>
                <span>{this.props.loadingMessage}</span>
            </div>
        );
```

This is what i am trying to do. If i get props top or left i need to plus that value to 50% from top and left. My example above not work and it just ignoring top and left attributes in my style.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you need to remove the `()` brackets from the properties. Then you can calculate them outside the `return`:

```
render(){
    // Assuming values are in pixels
    let topval = `calc(50% + ${top}px)`, leftval = `calc(50% + ${left}px)`;

    // rest of the code

    return(
        <div 
           style={{top: topval, left: leftval, transform: "translate(-50%,-50%)"}}
        />
    )
}
```

Also make sure to add units like `px`, `em` etc. when dealing with non-zero values otherwise the css is invalid.

For eg. `calc(50% - 10)` is wrong, `calc(50% - 10px)` works

Comment: This still ignoring top and left from style tag in return

Comment: @YoungL. What is meant by ignoring? Styles are not applied? Styles are applied but you don't get desired result? What is the value of `this.props.left` and `this.props.top`?

Comment: Styles are not applied. In my case top and left are 0. I am not using it yet so my calc function should be like this: ```top:calc(50% - 0)px```. When i put in style value (fe. 50%), not variable styles have applied

Comment: @YoungL. Also, you don't need to put brackets for the properties, I edited my answer

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Template Strings](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) to resolve this

```
style={{ top: `calc(50% + ${top})`, left: `calc(50% + ${left})` }}
```